# alignat inside align environment?

Tags: horizontal-alignment, equations, amsmath, align, multline

Why can't I nest an `alignat` environment in an `align` environment?

```
\begin{equation}
  \label{eq:115}
  \left\{
    \begin{aligned}
      \begin{alignat*}{2}
        &U(x,y,z,t)=\int\frac{x'-x}{r^3}[& &(x'-x)u(x',y',z',t)\\
        &                                &+&(y'-y)v(x',y',z',t)\\
        &                                &+&(z'-z)w(x',y',z',t)]d\omega',
      \end{alignat*}\\
        V(x,y,z,t)=.....,\quad W(x,y,z,t)=..... .
    \end{aligned}
  \right.
\end{equation}
```

The following compiles, but the first "+" sign of the second equation line doesn't align up very well with the phantom "+" of the first equation:

```
\begin{equation}
  \begin{dcases}
    \label{eq:115}
    {\begin{aligned}
        U(x,y,z,t)=\int\frac{x'-x}{r^3}[&\phantom{+}(x'-x)u(x',y',z',t)\\
                                        &+(y'-y)v(x',y',z',t)\\
                                        &+(z'-z)w(x',y',z',t)]d\omega',
      \end{aligned}}\\
    V(x,y,z,t)=\ldots\ldots,\quad W(x,y,z,t)=\ldots\ldots
  \end{dcases}
\end{equation}
```

thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

the easiest fix is to use your second attempt, but instead of just `\phantom{+}`,
surround the plus sign by empty groups to force the correct spacing:

```
\begin{equation}
  \begin{dcases}
    \label{eq:115}
    {\begin{aligned}
        U(x,y,z,t)=\int\frac{x'-x}{r^3}[&\phantom{{}+{}}(x'-x)u(x',y',z',t)\\
                                        &+(y'-y)v(x',y',z',t)\\
                                        &+(z'-z)w(x',y',z',t)]d\omega',
      \end{aligned}}\\
    V(x,y,z,t)=\ldots\ldots,\quad W(x,y,z,t)=\ldots\ldots
  \end{dcases}
\end{equation}
```

for your first attempt, `alignat*` isn't meant to be embedded.  instead, `alignedat`
(defined by `mathtools`) is appropriate.  but you will still need to add empty groups
around plus signs, in this case, the two that are between the ampersands:

```
\begin{equation}
  \label{eq:115}
  \left\{
    \begin{aligned}
      \begin{alignedat}{2}
        &U(x,y,z,t)=\int\frac{x'-x}{r^3}[& &(x'-x)u(x',y',z',t)\\
        &                                &{}+{}&(y'-y)v(x',y',z',t)\\
        &                                &{}+{}&(z'-z)w(x',y',z',t)]d\omega',
      \end{alignedat}\\
        V(x,y,z,t)=.....,\quad W(x,y,z,t)=..... .
    \end{aligned}
  \right.
\end{equation}
```

[image: output of code input]

i'm also not sure why you didn't use `cases`, but that's a niggle.

Comment: Ah, thanks. I didn't know about `alignedat*`.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to align parenthesis, this does it.

```
   \documentclass{article}
    \usepackage{mathtools}
    \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
    \begin{document}
    \begin{equation}
    \begin{dcases}
    \label{eq:115}
    \begin{split}
       U(x,y,z,t)=\int\frac{x'-x}{r^3}[\hphantom{{}+{}} &(x'-x)u(x',y',z',t)\\[-2\jot]
                                        {}+{}&(y'-y)v(x',y',z',t)\\
                                        {}+{}&(z'-z)w(x',y',z',t)]d\omega',
      \end{split}\\
    V(x,y,z,t)=\ldots\ldots,\quad W(x,y,z,t)=\ldots\ldots
   \end{dcases}
   \end{equation}
    \end{document}
```

[image]

You may prefer to remove `\hphantom{{}+{}}` if you wish.

Comment: since the `+` signs continue an existing formula, you should put empty groups around them to get the correct spacing: `{}+{}`.

Comment: @barbarabeeton Thanks for the official confirmation.

Answer (score 1):

A few ideas on how to typeset your formulas.

### Code

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools} % loads amsmath
\begin{document}

\begin{align}
  U(x,y,z,t) & = \int\frac{x'-x}{r^3} (x',y',z',t)
    \bigl[ (x'-x)u + (y'-y)v + (z'-z)w \bigr] d\omega' \\
  V(x,y,z,t) & = \ldots \\
  W(x,y,z,t) & = \ldots
\end{align}

\begin{equation}\left\{\begin{aligned}
  U(x,y,z,t) & = \int\frac{x'-x}{r^3} (x',y',z',t)
    \bigl[ (x'-x)u + (y'-y)v + (z'-z)w \bigr] d\omega' \\
  V(x,y,z,t) & = \ldots \\
  W(x,y,z,t) & = \ldots
\end{aligned}\right.\end{equation}

\begin{equation}\left\{\begin{gathered}
  \begin{multlined}
  U(x,y,z,t) = \int\frac{x'-x}{r^3}  \\
    \bigl[ (x'-x)u(x',y',z',t) + (y'-y)v(x',y',z',t) + (z'-z)w(x',y',z',t) \bigr] \\
    d\omega'
  \end{multlined} \\
  V(x,y,z,t) = \ldots \hfill\\
  W(x,y,z,t) = \ldots \hfill
\end{gathered}\right.\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

### Output

[image]

Comment: I do want the 2nd and 3rd equations on one line, though.